# WordPress REST API: comment and like count

Tags: javascript, wordpress-rest-api

What's the easiest way to fetch the number of comments and the number of likes a post has?

I don't see any usefull field when fetching a post (with a request like https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2018-07-21T15:05:44.000Z)

I'm currently using javascript issuing direct requests with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Answer (score 7):

If you have edit access to the code of the site your are requesting, you could add the field to the responses provided by the JSON API.

Something like this:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    \register_rest_field( 'post', 'comment_count', [
        'get_callback' => function ( $post ) {
            return (int) wp_count_comments( $post['id'] )->approved;
        },
        'schema'       => [
            'description' => 'List number of comments attached to this post.',
            'type'        => 'integer',
        ],
    ] );
});
```

If you don't have access to the site you are requesting, you can have the comments added to the response by send `?_embed=true` at the end of the URL and simply count the replies.

Something like this:

```js
const {data} = await Axios.get( 'https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=2018-07-21T15:05:44.000Z&_embed=true' );

data.map( post => {
    console.log( post._embedded.replies.length );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so much a JavaScript related question but here's an answer anyway.

The easiest way to get the number of comments for any post aside from adding a custom endpoint to the REST API is to use the comments endpoint (https://site/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1234&per_page=1) and use the response's `X-WP-Total` header.